# C# XNA Creating a List?

Tags: c#, list, xna

I'm trying to make a list to store all my instances of my `Trail` class but it is giving me this following error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.list<Jumper.Trail>' is less accessible than field 'Jumper.Main.trails'

I am using this following line of code (where it is erroring):

```
public static List<Trail> trails = new List<Trail>();
```

here is my Trail.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Jumper
{
    public class Trail
    {
        public int width;
        public static float angle;
        //The current position of the Sprite
        public Vector2 pos = Vector2.Zero;
        //The texture object used when drawing the sprite
        public Texture2D trail;

        public Trail()
        {
            angle = Player.rotation;
            pos.X = Player.pos.X;
            pos.Y = Player.pos.Y;
        }

        //Load the texture for the sprite using the Content Pipeline
        public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager, string theAssetName)
        {
            trail = theContentManager.Load<Texture2D>(theAssetName);
        }

        //Draw the sprite to the screen
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch theSpriteBatch)
        {
            theSpriteBatch.Draw(trail, new Vector2(pos.X, pos.Y), Color.White);
        }

        public void updateTrail()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if your list is initialized?

Comment: I have a suspicion that the code you've posted is different from the code that you're trying to compile.  That, or you have two classes with the same name, and you've not posted enough code to clarify what's causing the ambiguity.  Whatever the reason, your compiler thinks that the `Trail` class is less accessible than the list that contains it, i.e. the list is a public field and `Trail` is a private class.

Answer (score 1):

`private static List<Trail> trails = new List<Trail>();` ?

Answer (score 0):

> A static class is basically the same as a non-static class, but there
>   is one difference: a static class cannot be instantiated. In other
>   words, you cannot use the new keyword to create a variable of the
>   class type.

Direct quote from: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So pretty much, you just have to remove the static tag, that's all.

Sorry if this more than just a bit late. =\